# Set interval in a nested loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a nested loop in a function which takes a while to load on IE8 and results in an unresponsive page.

I have a loading bar which 'freezes' when the script is running.

How can I use `setInterval()` to stop processing JS after each iteration to make it appear the loading bar is still moving and make it appear that the page is responsive?

The function is:

```
function createDropDown() {
    var target = $('#mainList');
    for (var i = 0; i < info.books.length; i++) {
      var gnrval = info.books[i].genre
      var catval = info.books[i].category
      for (var j = 0; j < info.books[i].publishers.length; j++) {
        var pubval = info.books[i].publishers[j].publisher
        if (typeof app.cache.pub[pubval] == 'undefined') {
          app.cache.pub[pubval] = {
            'ul': $('<li class="publisher" data-value="' + pubval + '"><a href="#" class="sdeep">' + pubval + '</a><ul class="sub-menu" data-title="Publishers"></ul></li>').appendTo(target).children('ul'),
            'aut': {}
          };

        }
        var ulauthors = app.cache.pub[pubval].ul;

        for (var k = 0; k < info.books[i].publishers[j].authors.length; k++) {
          var autval = info.books[i].publishers[j].authors[k].name + ' (' + gnrval + ')'
          var aut_val = info.books[i].publishers[j].authors[k].name
          if (typeof app.cache.pub[pubval].aut[autval] == 'undefined') {
            app.cache.pub[pubval].aut[autval] = $('<li class="author" data-value="' + autval + '"><a href="#" class="sdeep">' + autval + '</a><ul class="sub-menu" data-title="Authors"></ul></li>').appendTo(ulauthors).children('ul')
          }
          var ulyears = app.cache.pub[pubval].aut[autval]
          console.log(ulyears)

          var gItems = []
          for (var m = 0; m < info.books[i].publishers[j].authors[k].yearsPublished.length; m++) {
            var yearval = info.books[i].publishers[j].authors[k].yearsPublished[m]
            var year = ulyears.find('.year[data-value="' + yearval + '"]')
            if (year.size() == 0) {
              var id = ++count
              gItems.push('<li class="year" data-value="' + yearval + '"><a id="selyear' + id + '" class="addone" data-id="' + id + '" data-year="' + yearval + '" data-pub="' + pubval + '" data-aut="' + aut_val + '" data-cat="' + catval + '" data-gnr="' + gnrval + '">' + yearval + '</a></li>')
            }
          }
          ulyears.append(gItems.join(''))
        };
      };
    };
```

I tried adding:

```
setTimeout(function () {
//last nested loop code here
        timeout();
    }, 1000);
```

But obviously it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

- You should start by breaking this gigantic function down. Simple tip: [Principle of single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
- Nesting loops squares the number of operations done. I suggest simplifying your data so that it can be done in one loop or a series of loops, and not nested loops. This would mean unnesting the data or structuring it in a way that you can simply do one pass.

  A caveat is that the data will multiply in size, so it's a tradeoff between payload size and processing performance. Here's an example, where a case of locating the "geo" book would take several searches on the first data structure, but would only be a simple `filter` on the second data structure.

  ```
  // So you loop through the properties of books, then another loop through math
  // then another loop through science, then you get your "geo". Loops: 3
  {
    books : {
      math : ['algebra','trigo','solids'],
      science : ['bio','geo','psycho']
    }
  }

  // Here, var geoBook = array.filter(function(book){return book.topic === 'geo'})[0];
  // Loops: 1 (filter is essentially a loop)

  [
    {
      type : 'book',
      subject : 'math',
      topic : 'algebra'
    },{
      type : 'book',
      subject : 'math',
      topic : 'trigo'
    },{
      type : 'book',
      subject : 'math',
      topic : 'solids'
    },{
      type : 'book',
      subject : 'science',
      topic : 'bio'
    },{
      type : 'book',
      subject : 'science',
      topic : 'geo'
    },{
      type : 'book',
      subject : 'science',
      topic : 'psycho'
    },
  ]
  ```
- To avoid freezing the browser, you need to "defer" operations using timers. You can use `setInterval` with a counter instead of loops. Here's a simple example:

  ```
  function each(array,iterator){
    var i = 0, length = array.length;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
      iterator.call(array,array[i]);
      if(++i >= length) clearInterval(timer);
    },1000);
  }

  each([1,2,3,...10000],function(n){
    console.log(n);
  })
  ```